# R-Project Barplot Colors

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I am new to R, and I am trying to create a simple barplot.  I have been able to create a barplot with the correct values, but only a single color for all bars.  If I change the code slightly ( using table() instead of as.table() ), I get the wrong values, but the correct colors on the graph.  How can I get the as.table() to accept multiple colors in a graph?  Here is an altered version of my code:

```
a=30
b=20
c=10
d=15
x=matrix(c(a,b,c,d),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)   
colnames(x)=c("Label1","Label2","Label3","Label4")  
    rownames(x)=c("Percentage")  
    x=as.table(x)  
    color=c("red","blue","green","orange")
barplot(x,main="X",ylab="Percent",cex.names=0.75,col=color)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in a vector instead of a table should do the trick:

```
barplot(x[1, ], main="X", ylab="Percent", cex.names=0.75, col=color)
```

Or

```
barplot(x["Percentage", ], main="X",ylab="Percent",cex.names=0.75, col=color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  That solved a very frustrating and seemingly easy dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `beside = TRUE` argument:

```
barplot(x, beside = TRUE, main="X", ylab="Percent", cex.names=0.75, col=color)
```

[image]